# React Native and this keyword

Tags: react-native

I'm integrating Facebook login into a React Native app that I'm building. I have the following code:

```
class FacebookButton extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchAccessToken = this.fetchAccessToken.bind(this);
  }

  facebookButtonPressed() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then((result) => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log('Login Cancelled');
      } else {
          this.fetchAccessToken();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
    });

  }

  fetchAccessToken() {
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
        const { accessToken } = data
        console.log(accessToken);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console('Error getting access token');
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
          onPress={this.facebookButtonPressed}
          title="Sign In with Facebook"
          color="#000000"
      />
    );
  }

}
```

However, I keep getting the error that the `fetchAccessToken` method is not a function. On first instinct, I thought that the issue `this` keyword was the issue. So I began with adding the above construct and binding `this` to it. I assumed here that `this` meant `FacebookButton`. i.e. I assumed that whenever I called `this.fetchAccessToken()` it would call the method. However, this didn't work.

I then continued reading and there were several references stating that I should use `Arrow functions` as arrow functions don't have a `this` associated with this function and this `this.fetchAccessToken()` would only have one context i.e. `FacebookButton`. However, this still isn't working.

So I have questions:

1. What are the exact issues that are causing the above code to not work? A details intuition would be appreciated. I'm taking React Native for a spin for the first time.
2. What would the fix be?

**Update**

The answer to question 2 is to add `.bind(this)` to the button like so:

```
<Button
    onPress={this.facebookButtonPressed.bind(this)}
    title="Sign In with Facebook"
    color="#000000"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to bind   `facebookButtonPressed()` in the constructor to reference `this` for the `fetchAccessToken` as

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.facebookButtonPressed = this.facebookButtonPressed.bind(this)
        this.fetchAccessToken = this.fetchAccessToken.bind(this);
    }
```

> When a function is invoked, an activation record, otherwise known as an **execution context**, **is created**. This record contains *information about where the function was called from* (the call-stack), *how the function was invoked, what parameters were passed, etc*.

Right now that is not referenced, unless you *bind it*.

Here are some of the different ways of [`binding`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).The methods have been explained by their *pros* and *cons*

Also you can learn more about `this` from [`here`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md#whats-this)